# Fatal error: Call to undefined function page_header() after migrating Website

Tags: php, web

I have migrated our website to a newer server and keep getting issues like " Fatal error: Call to undefined function page_header()  ... "
This is the index.php

```
<?php
require('includes/app_header.php');
authorize_user();
page_header();
?>
        <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center"><span class="style3">Welcome to GEOTRACKER</span>.</p>            <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
          <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>    <p align="center">  </p>     
<?  page_footer();  ?>
```

And here is my page header function:

```
//draw common html header section
function page_header()
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>GEOTRACKER</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<!--<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="includes/rte/richtext.js"></script>-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions.js"></script>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="includes/jscalendar/skins/aqua/theme.css" title="Aqua" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="includes/jscalendar/calendar-brown.css" title="brown" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {background-color: #EEEEEE; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:8pt;}
.style3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0066FF;
}

div.frame_like {
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: scroll; 
}

-->
</style>
</head>

<body style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="9" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#888888">
    <table align="center" border=0 bgcolor="#EEEEEE" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#999999" height="25" align="right" style="padding-right:15px">&nbsp;<?php if($_SESSION['logged']) {echo '<a href="logout.php" class="subtitle">logout</a>';} ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#AAAAAA" style="padding-left:5px"><?php if($_SESSION['logged']) {echo site_navigation();} ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="300px" align="center" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" valign="top">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- BEGIN OF SPECIFIC PART -->
<?
}
```

This works if I just manually insert it.

Comment: what's the folder structure on the new server? Change to require_once('includes/app_header.php'); and let me know what error you are getting

Comment: If page_header(); is called from require('includes/app_header.php'); then it looks as though it is not finding the required file.

Comment: It is setup like the last server. The index.php file is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\geotracker\ and the app_header.php is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\geotracker\includes

Comment: When I change it to require_once... I receive the same error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function page_header() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\geotracker\index.php on line 8


Call Stack


#

Time

Memory

Function

Location

1 0.0001 103176 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the end of you code to this

```
<!-- BEGIN OF SPECIFIC PART -->
<?php } ?>
```

The function is not being closed

Comment: Sorry, I am not to sure exactly where you would like me to insert this code. Do you want me to put it at the end of my function page_header() ?

Comment: This includes the top too.. `<?php function page_header() { ?>` and at the end `<?php } ?>` - Simply put, you're not wrapping your documents with `<?php` when needed.

Comment: I have <?php  at the top of my app_header.php then when I make page_header "function page_header()
{
?>" and at the end of page_header I have "<? 
}" and at the end of the file I have "?>"

Comment: The website files work on the old server and I haven't changed any of the code. I copied the entire folder and just pasted it in.

Comment: is the  some where, the function is not being closed off, that is why it is not working (I've tested this) edit the end of you second block of code to match what I have above, also your new server may not allow  php short tags

Comment: FYI you can change that setting in php.ini.